# Can I cook apple peels in my applesauce in a cheesecloth bundle?

Tags: boiling, apples, infusion

I like to include the peels when I make applesauce to get the benefit of the nutrients in the peels*, but I strain them out afterward for the sake of texture. This is a messy, sticky, time-consuming process, and it makes it harder to maintain a chunky texture to the applesauce.

It occurred to me today that perhaps I could make a sort of bouquet garni with the peels in a cheesecloth pouch and then just lift that out afterward (maybe give it a quick squeeze). Would this work? Would the cheesecloth change the flavor of the sauce? Any other concerns I should watch out for?

---

*I do know [the difference isn't huge](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/02/22/ask-well-the-nutrients-in-fruits-and-veggies/?_r=0), but old habits die hard.

Answer (score 3):

You might be better off using a synthetic jam-straining bag. These have larger holes and are less absorbent and easier to clean. You will also extract more of the pulp from the layer of fruit stuck to the peel.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I don't have one of those, though, so I will try cheesecloth first (since I generally have that on hand) and see if I think it would be worth it to purchase something new.

Comment: That's what I'd do too.

Answer (score 2):

If you use cheesecloth just make sure it either hasn't been used before or it has been cleaned thoroughly with scalding hot water. If you just smell it, you'll be able to tell if there is any residue on the cheesecloth that will transfer flavor/smell to the applesauce. Cheesecloth can be hard to clean, but with a new cheesecloth, you'll definitely have success with your idea!

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence! I don't generally try to re-use cheesecloth for anything wet, so I think I should be clear there. I'm going to try it tonight, we'll see how it goes.